# Crop Rotated Shape In HTML

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have a colored div that has been rotated 45 degrees and was wondering if there is way to crop the edges of it so that it fits within a certain boundry. (eg: a 45 degree line through a square that is cut off where it touches the square)

Here is the code:

```css
#parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;  
}
#child {
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg); 
}
.red_stripe {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position:absolute;
}
#gap {
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id = "parent">
  <div id = "child">
    <div class = "red_stripe"></div>
    <div id = "gap"></div>
    <div class = "red_stripe"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have recreated this in JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/RBlair/s9qusfvv/2/

So what should happen is that the red bar should be cut off where it meets the black border on the right and along the bottom sides (I am not worried about it exceeding the boundary at the top or left, just the right side and the bottom)

Comment: You want this? [example using overflow hidden](http://jsfiddle.net/pyn2jawb/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `overflow:hidden` to `#parent`

```css
#parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#child {
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.red_stripe {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
#gap {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
    <div class="red_stripe">
    </div>

    <div id="gap">
    </div>

    <div class="red_stripe">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

## Let's reduce the HTML required

### Pseudo element background

Use `overflow: hidden`, but create the lines with a [`::before` pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) and no extra HTML.

We can use:

- inner box shadow to create the lines (useful as it does not take up space like a border)
- `position: absolute` to position the `:before` along with a percentage height, width, left and right
- `position: relative` on the div so that the pseudo element is positioned in relation to it

### Complete Example

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 50px #F00;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```